# Como traduzir "Controle publicitário de alimentos ao público infantil" para inglês?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução

Preciso de traduzir "Controle publicitário de alimentos ao público infantil" para inglês, mas estou na dúvida quanto ao público infantil.

Vi que por vezes é traduzido somente como "children", as vezes como "child audiences".

Como posso traduzir esta frase por completo?

Comment: Michel, editei a pergunta para a tentar melhorar. Mas a pergunta é tua - se discordares das edições, não hesites em as ajustar ou reverter.

Comment: Não é o que tu perguntas, mas creio que o que queres dizer se exprime melhor por "controlo da publicidade alimentar ". O que lá tens sugere-me 'controlo de alimentos através de publicidade'

Answer (score 2):

Olhando no [linguee.pt](https://www.linguee.pt/portugues-ingles/traducao/voltada+para+o+p%C3%BAblico+infantil.html), há duas opções que se repetem mais:

1 - children, eg. -> **Obras extensas para o público infantil também são editadas** traduzido para: *Long books for children are also published*

2- children public, eg. -> **A Hydrogen conta com uma linha de 27 produtos voltada para o público infantil** traduzido para: *Hydrogen counts with a line of 27 products turned to the children public*

Há apenas uma menção a **audiences**. Porém, como estás a falar de algo voltado a publicidade, também vejo como adequado *child audience*, no singular, conforme essa tradução do espanhol para o inglês -> **General Mills tiene otros sitios Web que están destinados en su totalidad o parcialmente a la audiencia infantil.** para *General Mills does have other websites that are geared in whole or in part to a child audience*.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz umas tantas buscas no Google Books para ver o que é que o pessoal escreve em inglês. Retira as tuas próprias conclusões.

**Número de resultados das buscas no Google Books**

```
                           children      child audiences     a child audience
Advertising aimed at        6.140              1                    1
Advertising directed at     5.440              2                    1
Advertising to             45.200             10                   13
```

Leitura da tabela: por exemplo, ["Advertising aimed at children"](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&biw=1366&bih=626&tbm=bks&ei=d01LXIS1AuGV0AbUiqy4DQ&q=%22advertising%20aimed%20at%20children%22&oq=%22advertising%20aimed%20at%20children%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...315328.316941.0.320507.6.6.0.0.0.0.181.592.5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.rGERXl8gIfM) retornou seis mil, cento e quarenta resultados.

Comment: que idéia ótima, parabéns pela resposta!

Comment: @Peixoto, obrigado. É a minha tática habitual para ver qual a maneira mais idiomática de dizer algo em inglês.